# Set list to data according to key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD Array like this in `scala-spark`:

```
Array[(String,Int)]= Array((A1:B,1), (A1:A,10), (A2:C,5), (A2:E,5), (A3:D,3))
```

and i need to group it by the first parameter `A1 or A2 or A3` so as each of these be a list containing numbers respectively like this:

```
List( A1:(1,10), A2:(5,5), A3:(3) )
```

please help me

Comment: How does this relate to `apache-spark`? Are these actually `RDD`s and not Arrays? If so, I suggest starting by reading the documentation of RDD functions `groupByKey` and `keyBy`, or `groupBy`, and then `map` or `mapValues`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it as an `RDD`, we can do it following way.

```
scala> val x = List(("A1:B",1),("A1:A",10),("A2:C",5),("A2:E",5),("A3:D",3))
x: List[(String, Int)] = List((A1:B,1), (A1:A,10), (A2:C,5), (A2:E,5), (A3:D,3))
scala> x.map( a=> (a._1.split(":"),a._2))
res1: List[(Array[String], Int)] = List((Array(A1, B),1), (Array(A1, A),10), (Array(A2, C),5), (Array(A2, E),5), (Array(A3, D),3))

scala> res1.map(a => (a._1(0),a._2))
res12: List[(String, Int)] = List((A1,1), (A1,10), (A2,5), (A2,5), (A3,3))

scala> val rdd = sc.makeRDD(res12)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[15] at makeRDD at <console>:33

scala> rdd.groupByKey()
res13: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = ShuffledRDD[16] at groupByKey at <console>:36
scala> res13.collect

res14: Array[(String, Iterable[Int])] = Array((A3,CompactBuffer(3)), (A1,CompactBuffer(1, 10)), (A2,CompactBuffer(5, 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
val data = Array(("A1:B", 1), ("A1:A", 10), ("A2:C", 5), ("A2:E", 5), ("A3:D", 3))
val grpData = data.groupBy(f => f._1.split(":")(0)).map(x => (x._1 + ":(" + x._2.map(_._2).mkString(",") + ")")).toList
println(grpData)
```